# How can replace a specific line in a text file with a shell script?

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I am trying to replace a specific line in a txt file with my shell script, for example;

```
cat aa.txt:
auditd=0
bladeServerSlot=0
```

When I run my script I would like to change "bladeServerSlot" to 12 as following;

```
cat aa.txt:
auditd=0
bladeServerSlot=12
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Example : `perl -ne '$_ =~ s/bladeServerSlot\=0/bladeServerSlot\=12/; print $_;' aa.txt`

Comment: That could be written much nicer with `perl -pe 's/bladeServerSlot=0/bladeServerSlot=12/' aa.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` and backreferencing:

```
sed -r '/bladeServerSlot/ s/(^.*)(=.*)/\1=12/g' inputfile
```

Using `awk` , this will search for the line which contains `bladeServerSlot` and replace the second column of that line.

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}/bladeServerSlot/{$2=12}1' inputfile
```

Comment: whoever downvoted, please have some courtesy to explain the reason for downvote.

Comment: Seems like the sed would be cleaner as `/^bladeServerSlot/s/=.*$/=12/`

Comment: sed '/^bladeServerSlot/s/=.*$/=12/g' aa.txt > output.txt

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 's/bladeServerSlot=\K\d+/12/' aa.txt  > output.txt
```

The `\K` is a [particular form](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) of the [positive lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), which discards all previous matches. So we need to replace only what follows.  The `s/` is applied by default to [$_](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables), which contains the current line. The [`-p`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) prints `$_` for every line, so all other lines are copied.  We redirect output to a file.

Answer (score -1):

Is it really necessary to replace the line in your example? As `bladeServerSlot` is a variable you could reset the value.

```
bladeServerSlot=`any command`
```

Or you could just let this variable be filled by a Parameter provided to this script.

```
bladeServerSlot=$1
```

With `$1`being the first parameter of your script. I think this would be the cleaner way do solve your issue than to do fancy regex here. The sed/perl solutions will work, but they are not very clear to other people reading your script.